# Stacked bar chart, y domain

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/hBWoIIyzcHELGyewOyZE?p=preview

I'm trying to create a simple stacked bar chart.

The bars go above the top of the chart which I think is a problem with the domain

I also need a scale on the y axis which I think is to do with the y domain.

Is it the y domain that controls the height of the bars and scales shown on the y axis

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, (d)=>{
    return d
})])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list of the issues so far:

First, your `y` domain is not correctly set. It should use the stacked data:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(stackedSeries, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
        return d[0] + d[1];
    });
})])
```

Second, the math for the `y` and `height` of the rectangles is wrong. It should be:

```
.attr('height', (d) => {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[0] + d[1]);
})

.attr('y', (d) => {
    return y(d[0] + d[1]);
})
```

Finally, use the x scale for the `x` position:

```
.attr('x', (d, i) => {
    return x(d.data.day)
})
```

Here is the code with those changes:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 40,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 40
}

var width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom

var data = [{
    day: 'Mon',
    apricots: 120,
    blueberries: 180,
    cherries: 100
  },
  {
    day: 'Tue',
    apricots: 60,
    blueberries: 185,
    cherries: 105
  },
  {
    day: 'Wed',
    apricots: 100,
    blueberries: 215,
    cherries: 110
  },
  {
    day: 'Thu',
    apricots: 150,
    blueberries: 330,
    cherries: 105
  },
  {
    day: 'Fri',
    apricots: 120,
    blueberries: 240,
    cherries: 105
  }
];

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')

var colors = ['#FBB65B', '#513551', '#de3163'];

var stack = d3.stack()
  .keys(['apricots', 'blueberries', 'cherries']);

var stackedSeries = stack(data);

// Create a g element for each series
var g = d3.select('g')
  .selectAll('g.series')
  .data(stackedSeries)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('series', true)
  .style('fill', (d, i) => {
    return colors[i];
  });

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.1)

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])

x.domain(data.map((d) => {
  return d.day
}))

y.domain([0, d3.max(stackedSeries, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d, function(d) {
    return d[0] + d[1];
  });
})])

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

// For each series create a rect element for each day
g.selectAll('rect')
  .data((d) => {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('height', (d) => {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[0] + d[1]);
  })

  .attr('y', (d) => {
    return y(d[0] + d[1]);
  })
  .attr('x', (d, i) => {
    return x(d.data.day)
  })

  .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
  .style("stroke", "#ccc");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```